# How can i convert my ec2 instance from http to https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

4 days ago I am trying but with no success to convert my ec2 AWS instance from http to https i add security group with inbound rule https and port 443 but when I type https://ec2instance.amazone.com it give can't reach the web site this is my security group inbound rule [image: this is my security group inbound rule]

Are there any steps left that I need to do? plz let your response in more details

Comment: Is your instance configured to serve HTTPS?

Comment: What do you mean by configure to serve HTTPS?SSL certificate

Comment: The security group whitelists inbound traffic on that port but doesn't enable HTTPS. Instead the web server service (such as Apache, Nginx etc) will need to be listening and serving traffic via HTTPS. Otherwise all traffic will still be served other HTTP still :)

Comment: Can you plz give me an answer with steps?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're running on the server to serve HTTP traffic?

Comment: I am running my instance on linux/ubunu with Nginx

Comment: I am running my instance on linux/ubunu with Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst enabling inbound traffic for HTTPS is a necessary step in serving encryption in transit for your end users it is not the only step that is required.

As your infrastructure comprises of a single EC2 instance your EC2 host would need to be configured to serve HTTPS requests. In NGINX you will need to set a listener for your hostname on the port 443 with ssl enabled. Additionally you will need to reference the SSL certificates location and the cipher suites you will accept during communication.

More information about the exact configuration required is available in the [Configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

The default SSLs installed on your server will not be valid for the domain you are serving, which will lead to your users receiving a warning when attempting to use your website. To get around this problem you will need to use one of the following solutions:

- Use a free (but valid) SSL generation service such as [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)
- Buy an SSL from a valid certificate authority.

For both of the above options you will require to have access to manage the DNS records of the domain you are purchasing SSL for.